noticeable floating-point errors in pytorch
self.running_outc = 32
            weight1 = weight[:self.running_outc]
            bias1 = bias[:self.running_outc] if self.bias is not None else None
            out1 = F.conv1d(input=x.cuda(),
                            weight=weight1.cuda(),
                            bias=bias1.cuda(),
                            stride=self.stride,
                            padding=self.padding,
                            dilation=self.dilation,
                            groups=self.groups)

            # self.running_outc = 64
            # weight2 = weight[:self.running_outc]
            # bias2 = bias[:self.running_outc] if self.bias is not None else None
            output = F.conv1d(input=x.cuda(),
                              weight=weight.cuda(),
                              bias=bias.cuda(),
                              stride=self.stride,
                              padding=self.padding,
                              dilation=self.dilation,
                              groups=self.groups)
            dif = sum((out1[:, :16] - output[:, :16]).view(-1))
            print(dif)

I slice the channels of the convolutional layer and it turns out that there is a significant error in the results of the corresponding channels, which introduces a serious result bias at the end of the DNN model.
Does anyone else have a similar problem?

I have test and found no difference, whether slice or not. You can try on cpu or reinstall a new version of torch
